# How can I combine overlapping path segments to get the full path in Perl?

Tags: perl, string, path

I'm really not loving Perl but I've got to use it for my current task.

Here is my problem... I have three strings, that make up elements of a full directory path (windows, but needs to work on *nix too). For example...

```
$root = "c:\\checkout\\omega";
$client = "abc\\mainline";
$build = "omega\\abc\\mainline\\host\\make";
```

I want to combine these to make a full path e.g.

```
"c:\\checkout\\omega\\abc\\mainline\\host\\make"
```

But there is overlap between the $build string and the `$root` and/or `$client` string. How can I combine these to get the full path and ignore the overlapping. `$client` can probably be ignored in this example but there are other cases where `$build may` overlap `$client` but not `$root`.

I can think of lots horrible messy ways to implement it but I assume (perhaps wrongly) that there is a simple, clean and maybe even elegant way of doing this since Perl is mainly about the text manipulation.

Some kind of string OR operation maybe. I foolishly tried...

```
($root . $client) | $build
```

But it is a bitwise operation and the result is junk!

Comment: Do the literal slashes not cause a problem? Not that you can use "/" on Windows as a directory seperator:

$root = "c:/checkout/omega";
$client = "abc/mainline";
$build = "omega/abc/mainline/host/make";

Comment: Currently the \ in double quotes is an escape character.  U need to escape them \\  or use single quotes (or q{}) instead.  Like Pod says u may find that using / works fine on Windows anyway.

Comment: This question is not clear, but there is likely to be a simple answer if you can be less ambiguous. What exactly are you trying to do? In your example you aren't combining all three path elements. Can you explain when the elements should be combined and when they should not?

Comment: You are likely to want to be using File::Spec but could you explain a bit further? I think that you mean that you need to remove path components up to and including $client in $build (leaving you with something like 'host\make' and then combining that remaining part with $root and $client to get something like '$root\$client\$remainder'. Is that right?

Comment: Doh! Yes, the '\\' for slashes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact you have three paths is confusing me a little, but if you want to find overlap between two, you could use a [back reference](http://amazing-perl.blogspot.com/2008/01/backreferences.html) in a regular expression.

For example:

```
$root = "c:\\checkout\\omega";
$build = "omega\\abc\\mainline\\host\\make";    

# Concatenate Strings
$path = "$root\\$build";
print "original ",$path,"\n";

# Look for overlap using a backreference
$path =~ /^.*(.+)\1.*$/;
print "overlap ",$1,"\n";

# Do a substitution to remove the overlap
$path =~ s/^(.*)(.+)\2(.*)$/\1\2\3/;
print "new ",$path,"\n";
```

This will produce the following output:

```
original c:\checkout\omega\omega\abc\mainline\host\make
overlap omega\
new c:\checkout\omega\abc\mainline\host\make
```

Comment: The regex for finding overlap would be better as /(.+)\1/.  Regexes will match anywhere in the string by default, so starting them with (non-capturing) ^.* or ending with .*$ is just meaningless noise.  Depending on your regex implementation, those can also slow things down substnatially by forcing backtracking, but I'm pretty sure the Perl implementation is optimized to avoid that performance hit.

Comment: Come to think of it...  You don't need to repeat the search in your final regex.  Changing it to s/$1// will probably work fine - the duplicated piece is in $1 from the previous regex, so just replace that with nothing.  As long as you don't include a /g modifier, it will replace only the first instance of the repeated text.  Or do it all in one shot with s/(.+)\1/$1/.  (Using \1 in the replace portion of s/// "is better written as $1", per "use warnings".)

Answer (score 4):

This regex below is better suited for eliminating duplicate path sequences.

```
qr{ ( 
      [\\/]  # 1. starts with a path break
      .+?    # 2. whatever
    )
    \1       # whatever was captured in the previous group 
             # it forces us to backtrack on #2 until we have duplicates
             # it will necessarily have a path break at the beginning
  }x;
```

The regex provided by Dave Webb works as long as there are no repeated *letters* in the path. Just make the last node `'mmake'` and it breaks.

I get:

```
original c:\checkout\omega\abc\mainline\omega\abc\mainline\host\mmake
overlap m
new c:\checkout\omega\abc\mainline\omega\abc\mainline\host\make
```

You want the repetition to be *directory names*, not characters.

Also a simple substitution is all that's needed. Chances are when you see `^.*` or `.*$` in a regex, it's not needed. And it isn't needed any more in this one.

In fact all of this can be done with:

```
$path =~ s/([\\\/]+.+?)\1/$1/;
```

Replace something and it's duplicate with that something.

#### [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec)

By the way, `File::Spec` is the accepted way to concatenate directories in a platform-independent fashion:

```
my $path = File::Spec->catfile( $root, $client, $build );
$path =~ s/([\\\/]+.+?)\1/$1/;
```

I have a minor pet peeve with `File::Spec`, though. I *like* using `/` for directories. And perl *works* with `/` in a windows environment. As long as I stay in the confines of perl, I never have to separate paths with the *escape* character (in the C family of languages). `File::Spec` forces backslashes to be consistent with the windows platform.

However, if that's what you're looking for, that's probably more reason to use it.

Comment: Using / doesn't force backslashes...  You can use other punctuation as your regex delimiters.  e.g., s|(/.+)\1|$1|, s{(/.+)\1}{$1}, etc.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman: I clarified that `File::Spec` forces backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

1. use single quotes to preserve the backslashes (if backslashes is what you want);
2. my $fullpath = join "", $root, $client, $build;

`join` is the 'glue' between the strings - in this case, empty or nothing.

The above gives:

```
c:\checkout\omegaabc\mainlineomega\abc\mainline\host\make
```

so if you need backslashes between the strings, use `join "\\"` instead which will give:

```
c:\checkout\omega\abc\mainline\omega\abc\mainline\host\make
```

With strings in double quotes, the character after the \ will be escaped. In single quotes, the literal string is preserved.

Then you can easily convert the backslashes to (*nix) forward slashes, but that's another process. With Perl, always `use strict;` which will helpfully point out any potential glitches when you run it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing if there are any rules to your structure (for eg. $client seems superfluous in your example?) but if there is then u can do things like this:

```
my $root  = 'c:\checkout\omega'; 
my $build = 'omega\abc\mainline\host\make';

# $root + $build minus first node
my $file = join '\\', $root, ( split /\\/, $build, 2 )[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can think of lots horrible messy
>   ways to implement it but I assume
>   (perhaps wrongly) that there is a
>   simple, clean and maybe even elegant
>   way of doing this

Yepp. Take a look at the [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path::Class) module. From your question it is not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but `Class::Path` let's you manipulate paths in a cross-platform way.